# Trying to fetch Json Result

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch the individual values from the obtained json result

```
{
  "_total": 1,
  "values": [{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "Example Technologies "
  }]
}
```

Now, I need to get the `_total` value. For that i am using

```
echo $res->_total;
```

which gives me 
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`
If i try like 
`echo $res['_total'];`
gives me

```
Warning: Illegal string offset '_total'
```

So, In what way, I can get the `_total` value.

Please help me in that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify this a bit for you: $res just contains a string-value, which happens to be in json format. This explains the errors you are getting.

Comment: PHP doesn't work directly with JSON strings.. you need to json_decode() them so to have php Object/array and work with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose data is

```
$data = '{"category_id":"10","username":"agent1","password":"82d1b085f2868f7834ebe1fe7a2c3aad:fG"}';
```

and you want to get particular parameter then

```
$obj = json_decode($data);

after 
$obj->{'category_id'} , $obj->{'username'} , $obj->{'password'}
```

May be this help you !

Comment: But the data is `{
  "_total": 1,
  "values": [{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "Example Technologies "
  }]
}` - so why suppose something else?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$obj = json_decode($res);
echo $obj->_total;
```

You need to decode the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the JSON string, or `$res` is not the result of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Example:

```
$json = '{
  "_total": 1,
  "values": [{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "Example Technologies "
  }]
}';

$res = json_decode($json);

echo $res->_total;
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to run the string through json_decode first https://www.php.net/json_decode
which will return an array.

Comment: `json_decode()` by default returns an object. You'll have to pass the second parameter as `TRUE` to have an array returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your String,

```
 $data = '{ "_total": 1, "values": [{ "id": 123456, "name": "Example Technologies " }] }';
$test = (array)json_decode($data);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r(objectToArray($test));
 die;
```

Function is here

```
function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }
```

May be its help you!!